# Is it safe to reheat chickpeas twice?

Tags: food-safety, reheating, chickpeas

I cooked a batch of garbanzo beans, immediately washed under cold tap water, drained 10-20 minutes, and transferred to the fridge to chill for a  few hours, then transferred to portioned freezer bags and put in the freezer

A few days later I took a portion, thawed in cold water 10-20 minutes, fully recooked it, drained at room temp for 10-20 minutes, squeezed out as much liquid as I could, transferred into airtight container and then put in the fridge to chill

After 3 days in the fridge I recooked it (the second time), drained, and immediately (while still piping hot) blended with ice cubes, tahini, lemon, salt, pepper and some of the (still hot) cooking liquid

I immediately transferred the mixture (now at about room temp) to an airtight container and put it in the freezer about 20 minutes to quickly cool down, then down to the fridge

How do I tell if it's still completely safe? (after 1 month in the freezer, then 3-4 days in the fridge, during which it was recooked and rechilled twice)